# Float last div next to the first one

Tags: html, css, css-float

This is my HTML

```
<div class="one">...</div>
<div class="two">...</div>
<div class="three">...</div>
<div class="four">...</div>
<div class="five">...</div>
```

How can I get this image by using only CSS? I guess with `float`, but how can I get the fifth div next to the first one?
Changing the HTML is NOT (!) an option.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first comment would be that class names *can't* start with a number, so I really hope that you *can* edit the HTML for that. To answer your question ignoring this fact, if each element has a class, this is pretty simple. Just do this:

```
div { 
    float: left; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;
    clear: left; }
div.5 { 
    float: none; 
    clear: none; 
    display: inline-block; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/mvwSL/

Comment: Thanks, this one was the solution!

Comment: Please accept this solution if it is the one you feel answers your question :)

Comment: I'll, one I'm sure it works for 100% :-) Still testing and fine tuning!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

**Float and negative margins:**

`.five{float:right; margin-top:-500px;}`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cuqtP/)

**Or margins only**

`.five{margin:-500px 0 0 200px;}`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9w8vF/)

**Or relative positioning:**

`.five{position:relative; top:-500px; left:200px;}`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/35CfC/)

**Or absolute positioning:**

`.five{position:absolute; top:0; right:0;}`

(Make sure the container is set to `position:relative;`)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yQMR4/)

Answer (score 0):

First, classes with numeric values are not valid. You're quite screwed if you can't change them... With proper classes, a solution might be:

CSS :

```
div {float:left;clear:left}
div.c5 {float:right}
```

jQuery

```
$("div.c5").insertBefore("div.c1")
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WvtSm/2/)

Comment: Yeah, I know. It was just for fast typing! Thanks for you answer. I can add CSS classes, but can't change the current values.

Answer (score 0):

Try below: It works as you required but horizontally, you want vertically. But am sure it might help you.

```css
#outer {
width: 500px;
margin: 300px 0 0 10px;
}

.inner {
background-color: red;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: left;
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
     <div id="outer">
      <div class="inner">1</div>
      <div class="inner">2</div>
      <div class="inner">3</div>
      <div class="inner">4</div>
      <div class="inner">5</div>
      <div class="inner">6</div>
      <div class="inner">7</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can remove it. doesn't matter here

Comment: Ok, but why did you put it there?

Comment: Oh, ok, so it doesn't matter here? :-)

Answer (score 0):

@Wex

```
div:last-child{
    float: none; 
    clear: none; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: What's different from Wex' answer?